# How to implement SSO using ADFS bypassing the ADFS login page in iOS app

Tags: ios, office365, single-sign-on, adfs, adfs3.0

I have an app where earlier there was only AD login which we directly authenticated the app via our own server API as a middleware. Now after implementing the ADFS on the server, we are getting the ADFS login page, which we would like to bypass in order to maintain the workflow. 
Basically we want to connect to Office 365 data via our own server and feed it to our app.

Does anyone know if even it is feasible to bypass that login page? ADFS v3.0

Comment: ADFS has two flows; passive (browser) and active (WCF).

Answer (score 0):

ADFS has two flows; passive (browser) and active (WCF).

You can bypass the login screen on passive by setting up the browser to do IWA.

Active will give you the flow you want i.e. authentication via a service.